# XQuery - perform replace/match operation on string

Tags: if-statement, replace, match, xquery

I have a string, say, `let $baseString := "stringToReplace-Rem-aining-String"`. I want to run a conditional test
to check if `$baseString` contains `"stringToReplace"` and `"-"`,
`if (fn:substring($baseString,1,15) = 'stringToReplace' and fn:matches($baseString, "(([-])+)"))`,
and if it does, I want to replace `'stringToReplace'` with `'replacedString'` and also `"-"` with `""` (blank), so, output string should be `replacedStringRemainingString`.
How can I achieve this in xQuery?

So far, I have got below 2 separate code block working - but I need to somehow combine the 2 together. And I don't really see the reason why I am using a for loop here, but this is the way I got this code block to execute without error.

```
let $baseString := "stringToReplace-Rem-aining-String"
for $x in $baseString return
if (fn:substring($baseString,1,15) = 'stringToReplace' and fn:matches($baseString, "(([-])+)")) 
then (fn:concat('replacedString',fn:substring($baseString,16,40))) 
 else ($baseString)
```

this gives result of
`replacedString-Rem-aining-String`
and

```
let $baseString := "stringToReplace-Rem-aining-String"
for $x in $baseString return
if (fn:substring($baseString,1,15) = 'stringToReplace' and fn:matches($baseString, "(([-])+)")) 
then (fn:replace($baseString, "(([-])+)", ""))
 else ($baseString)
```

this gives result of `stringToReplaceRemainingString` .

Any ideas please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try combining the `then`s to

```
then (
  let $tmp := fn:concat('replacedString',fn:substring($baseString,16,40))
  return fn:replace($tmp, "(([-])+)", "") 
)
```

This gets your expected output at least for the string in your question.

Comment: both this answer and the answer of @Michaelkay does what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
let $baseString := 'stringToReplace-Rem-aining-String'
return
if (matches($baseString, '^stringToReplace.*-'))  
then ('replacedString' || translate(substring($baseString, 16), '-', ''))
else $baseString
```